# IE7 not showing my Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, tooltip

the problem is that the tooltips shows and error in the script (don't know what could it be) in IE7

[Can you take a look??](http://www.dinterweb.com/grupocolono/index.php)

If you need any of the code or something else please ask...

Comment: We can't view a site running on your localhost. Please post the code.

Comment: First it would be nice if you provided either a working link or the code. Since I for some "weird" reason cant find your site on my localhost :)

Comment: LOL LOL LOL OMG SORRY... i give it to you in a sec

Comment: good luck. i took a look in IE, and it said your error is on line 3243243243242, which didnt help.

Comment: ... yeah for me it says "line 223788531 character 76" 
how can i know where is the error T^T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not in your js but in your php!

for istance, your code break, in the setupMap.js

```
    map: {
                id: 'colono',
                image: 'images/map/colono.png',
                //data: 'popups/colono.php',
                maps: [
                  ....
```

try to comment the `data: 'popups/colono.php',` and you'll see no error!

maybe you are sending a malformed json!?

Comment: you where right ^^, I got some commas at the end of my tooltip scripts inside the colono.php, thanks a lot n.n